# View Class Hierachy in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does VS Code inherently come with any tool other than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to view the entire class hierarchy within a project? Think similar to a Visual Studio solution or Eclipse project.

I've looked around the VS Code extension marketplace and have not seen one. It would be very useful to see this kind of tree for a TypeScript based project instead of seeing just the imports from a particular `.ts` file

If anyone knows of one, please share!

Answer (score -1):

If you're in the Explorer, the built-in OUTLINE view does exactly this. I am apparently not paying attention.

Comment: My VSCode outliner only appears to show the methods in the currently open JS file. How do I get it to show the class hierarchy for all JS classes in the project?

Comment: @SteveDekorte I'm also looking for this, I would like to see at least the hierarchy for the current class. Did you ever find anything?

Comment: I haven’t found anything yet. I ended up writing something to output the hierarchy on the console, but I’d still like something in the UI.

Comment: VS code Outline does *not* output class hierarchy.

Comment: This information is incorrect, the VSCode outline panel does not output class hierarchy

Answer (score -2):

If you click on an empty line in your file then when you press the small dots on the location hint above, it will show the first level members available, which more likely are going to be classes, constants and public methods like in my image: [image]